# proving that every set of zero Lebesgue outer measure is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

According to Terence Tao's *Introduction to Measure Theory*, a set $E \subset \mathbb R^d$ is said to be Lebesgue measurable if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^d$ containing $E$ such that $m^*(U\setminus E)\le \epsilon$.  Using this definition, I was able to show that every set $E$ with $m^*(E)=0$ was measurable.  Although the proof isn't very long, I wonder if there's a simpler way to see this than the arguments I used, as shown below:

Suppose $m^*(E)=0$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a countable union of boxes, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$, containing $E$, with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |B_n|<\epsilon$.  For each $B_n$, we then find an open box $C_n \supset B_n$ with volumn $|C_n| \le |B_n|+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.  As a result, $U \triangleq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$ is an open set containing $E$ with $m^*(U)\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |C_n|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(|B_n|+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\right)<2\epsilon$.  Clearly, $m^*(U\setminus E) \le m^*(U)$, so $E$ is measurable.

Is this proof correct?  Is there a more straightforward way to see it?  Thanks a lot!

EDIT: This question is related to [Are all measure zero sets measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365847/are-all-measure-zero-sets-measurable), with the differences being (1) the *definition* of measurability is different, (2) this question is more general; it's about $\mathbb R^d$ instead of $\mathbb R$, (3) I want to verify a proof with these differences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are all measure zero sets measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365847/are-all-measure-zero-sets-measurable)

Comment: @SahibaArora Thanks for pointing this out.  I've clarified the differences in the question.

Comment: Where you are implicitly headed here is that the exterior measure $m^*$ of some set $E$ can be equivalently defined as the infimum exterior measure over all open sets $O$ containing $E$. Adding that to your collection of lemmas will trivialize similar situations in the future :)

Comment: @R.G.  Indeed.  Thanks a lot!