# Intersection with the complement of a zero set does not affect outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that if $Z$ is a zero set and $\omega$ is an abstract outer measure, and $E$ and $X$ are sets, then

$\omega(X \cap E^c \cap Z^c)= \omega(X \cap E^c )$

This intuitively makes sense because $\omega(Z^c)$ should equal $\omega(M)$, where $M$ is the universe. So intersecting a set with $Z^c$ shouldn't affect the measure of that set. I'm not sure how to prove this though.

For context, this is part of a larger proof that if $E$ is measurable, then $E \cup Z$ is measurable.

Comment: Is a "zero set" any set of measure zero?

Comment: In the construction of a measure out of an outer measure, any  $A$ of outer measure $0$ are measurable in the sense of Caratheodory, that is for any $E\subset X$, $m^*(E)=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\setminus A)$. Of course, as $m^*(A\cap E)=0$ if $A$ has outer measure $0$. Review the construction of measures out of outer measures. For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064678/proving-the-caratheodory-criterion-for-lebesgue-measurability) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365847/are-all-measure-zero-sets-measurable)

Comment: Note: A set of zero measure is a _null set_; otoh a "zero set" is usually $\{x:f(x)=0\}$ for some function $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove:

> Let $\omega$ be an abstract outer measure and $Z$ be any set such that $\omega(Z)=0$. Then for any set $F$, $\omega(F \cap Z^c) = \omega(F)$ .

**Proof**: By the monotonicity of $\omega$, we have that
$$\omega(F \cap Z^c) \leq \omega(F) \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, by the sub-sdditiviy, we have
$$  \omega(F) \leq \omega(F \cap Z) + \omega(F \cap Z^c) $$
Since $\omega(F \cap Z) \leq  \omega( Z) =0$, we have that $  \omega(F \cap Z) =0$. So we have
$$  \omega(F) \leq \omega(F \cap Z^c) \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $\omega(F \cap Z^c) = \omega(F)$. $\square$

For the case in your question, just take $F=X \cap E^c$.